# There's no way to specify availability zone in openstack provider, is there?

Tags: juju

You can only choose which region, but not availability zone within that region?

Answer (score 2):

Correct.

There's a couple of outstanding bugs related *EC2* availability zones:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1183831
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1160667

This topic has come up in discussions again recently. There's work on "placement directives" (i.e. a way to describe where machines should be provisioned) soon to be under way, which will address availability zones and more.